# Grafana / influxDB: How many minutes was metric value=1 during selected period?

Tags: boolean, grafana, influxdb

Grafana / influxDB: So I have a boolean (0 or 1). I want to know how many minutes the value was 1 during a period I wish to select (several days). Can it be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It will be tricky to calculate it in the InfluxDB however, Grafana has a 3rd party [Discrete panel](https://grafana.com/plugins/natel-discrete-panel), where you can calculate it on the app/panel level. Panel calculation will be running in the browser, so it can be slow if you have many datapoints in the selected time period.

Comment: Thank you, will give it a shot!